# Which version of duplicate feature columns removal in machine learning is faster and why?

Tags: python, pandas

I am taking an ML course at Udemy and currently reading about Feature Engineering. There is a need to remove duplicate columns (feature) from the dataset and author has suggested two versions of the code.

Data Set Download [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6grb74hi5yozit0/data.csv?dl=0)

**Version 1**:
Version 1 uses matrix transpose and then applied `duplicated()` method as follows

```
data_unique = data.T.drop_duplicates(keep='first').T
```

This part of the code took around 9 seconds my PC to find out 52 duplicate features out of 350. The shape of data is `(92500, 350)` and my windows PC is running with `dual-core i5, 16 GB and 500 GB SSD`.
Runtime: `9.71 s ± 299 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

**Version 2**:
The instructor has suggested one more method as follows

```
# check for duplicated features in the training set
duplicated_feat = []
for i in range(0, len(X_train.columns)):
    if i % 10 == 0:  # this helps me understand how the loop is going
        print(i)

    col_1 = X_train.columns[i]

    for col_2 in X_train.columns[i + 1:]:
        if X_train[col_1].equals(X_train[col_2]):
            duplicated_feat.append(col_2)
```

Runtime: `2min 16s ± 4.97 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Eventually, this took more than `2 mins` to find out duplicated features **But instructor has claimed that this the faster method if I have big data.** Although, with my finding, I am not convinced by his claim.

Comment: How about using [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) to verify your finding with different input data sizes (and with multiple runs)?

Comment: @Sparky05 refer to using %%timeit at the top of your cell in your notebook so you can time it yourself.

Comment: Runtime metrics is updated into the Question. Thanks to all.

Comment: ...so, if your goal is to figure out how the two versions scale over time, the best thing to do is measure how they scale! Change your dataset sizes, ensuring that you're avoiding trivial cases (if you create a bigger dataset by making N copies of a smaller one, that's likely to generate nonrepresentative benchmarks), retest, and plot the relationships. If there's *really* a big constant-factor offset making the second slower with small datasets, but better big-O behavior making it better with large ones, it'll come out in the graph.

Comment: Of course, your instructor *really could* be wrong -- it could even be that they were right when they came up with the course, but that `drop_duplicates()` has been rewritten to use a more efficient algorithm since then!

Comment: It seems he is. Version 2 is not only taking longer time but also larger manual coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **best** way to do this is to use `numpy` to find the unique indices along columns (`axis=1`), then slice the original.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

_, idx = np.unique(df.to_numpy(), axis=1, return_index=True)
df_uniq = df.iloc[:, np.sort(idx)]
```

---

Some timings on my machine:

```
# First a sanity check they are equivalent (lucikly all values are non-Null)
(df_uniq == df.T.drop_duplicates(keep='first').T).all().all()
True

%%timeit 
_, idx = np.unique(df.to_numpy(), axis=1, return_index=True)
df_uniq = df.iloc[:, np.sort(idx)]
#3.11 s ± 60.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df.T.drop_duplicates(keep='first').T
#25.9 s ± 112 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I wont even bother with the loop because it's just bad.

Comment: what was reported time of my version 1 and version 2 code in your PC.

Comment: @Samual 25.9s for version 1, it’s  in the timing test. I didn’t have the patience to wait for version 2 since it’s so long, and will not beat the NumPy version